# how do I do patch with ng-resource when dealing with aggregate REST endpoint

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I have a fairly simple CRUD model for my REST. My problem is how to handle PATCH or PUT when I aggregate for performance and to keep common business logic server-side.

Let's say I have a company and departments. Here are the CRUD endpoints

```
GET /companies // list all companies
GET /companies/25 // GET company with ID 25
GET /departments  // list all departments
GET /departments/65 // GET department with ID 65
```

Before, the client would `GET /companies/25` which returns

```
{id:"25",name:"my firm",departments:["65","72","10]}
```

it would then do separate calls for the departments. (yes, I could use hyperlinks in the response, but this is a simple example)

Now I want to create an aggregation endpoint, so it is a single call. `GET /companies/25` will return

```
{id:"25",name:"my firm",departments:[
   {id:"65", name:"Marketing"},
   {id:"72", name:"Sales"},
   {id:"10", name:"R&D"},
]}
```

(the real situation is much more complex)

The problem is that this becomes a single `$resource`. If I want to `PUT` or `PATCH` whatever has changed, it might send lots of information, since `ng-resource` does not understand that just the `id` and `name` are part of the department `"25"` and should be sent, while the rest were provided as a convenience.

How do I use `PATCH`/`PUT` with `ng-resource` when the endpoint is aggregated?

Conversely, if I have a separate endpoint URL for the aggregation, e.g.

```
GET /full_companies/25
```

Then it gets even more difficult, because `ng-resource` does not understand one URL for query (`GET`) and another for command (`PUT`/`PATCH`/`DELETE`)?

Comment: You can override methods so you have full control on $resource

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Oh, that is a good point. I already override so that `$save()` can be patch or put or post, depending on my needs, and I keep track of the pristine items, so that might work.

Comment: I just realized that it is still difficult. That might solve patching the highest level item, in this case the `/companies/25`, but what if I need to patch one of the `departments`? Beforehand, because it was a separate inefficient call, I could, at least, patch it directly. Now?